# Comparsion of two files in two scripts to one script

Tags: awk, compare

I have two scripts for comparing two files.

First script compare $3 column:

```
> awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$4;next}{$2=$2 "\t"(a[$2]?a[$2]:"-")}1' file1 file2
```

Second script compare $2 column:

```
 > awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$4;next}{$2=$2 "\t"(a[$2]?a[$2]:"-")}1' file1 file2
```

You see a differences 
`NR==FNR{a[$3]=$4;next}` and 
`NR==FNR{a[$2]=$4;next}` and 
I would like to write into one script so something like
 `NR==FNR{a[$2 || $3]=$4}`

Please could you help me? 
If you want I could share files and more informations.

INPUT: 
File 1

```
chr1    11796320    11796321    MTHFR
chr1    169549810   169549811   F5
chr1    173917077   173917078   SERPINC1
chr2    48962781    48962782    FSHR
chr4    121696961   121696962   ANXA5
chr4    121697010   121697011   ANXA5
chr4    121697036   121697037   ANXA5
chr4    121697055   121697056   ANXA5
chr11   46739504    46739505    F2
chr13   20189510    20189511    GJB2
chr13   20189546    20189547    GJB2
```

File2

```
chr1    11796321    G   0   WILD    ADP=1026
chr1    169549811   C   0   WILD    ADP=940
chr1    173917078   C   0   WILD    ADP=501
chr2    48962782    C   T   HET ADP=1665
chr4    121696962   C   T   HET ADP=212
chr4    121697011   A   0   WILD    ADP=184
chr4    121697037   T   0   WILD    ADP=111
chr4    121697037   tccc    0   INDEL   AINDEL
chr4    121697056   C   0   WILD    ADP=112
chr11   46739505    G   0   WILD    ADP=202
chr13   20189511    C   0   WILD    ADP=326
chr13   20189546    AC  A   INDEL   ADP=164
chr13   20189547    C   0   WILD    ADP=3
```

OUTPUT:

```
chr1    11796321    MTHFR   G   0   WILD    ADP=1026
chr1    169549811   F5  C   0   WILD    ADP=940
chr1    173917078   SERPINC1    C   0   WILD    ADP=501
chr2    48962782    FSHR    C   T   HET ADP=1665
chr4    121696962   ANXA5   C   T   HET ADP=212
chr4    121697011   ANXA5   A   0   WILD    ADP=184
chr4    121697037   ANXA5   T   0   WILD    ADP=111
chr4    121697037   ANXA5   tccc    0   INDEL   AINDEL
chr4    121697056   ANXA5   C   0   WILD    ADP=112
chr11   46739505    F2  G   0   WILD    ADP=202
chr13   20189511    GJB2    C   0   WILD    ADP=326
chr13   20189546    GJB2    AC  A   INDEL   ADP=164
chr13   20189547    GJB2    C   0   WILD    ADP=3
```

Comment: Please, provide some reasonable samples of the source files and the expected output.

Comment: That syntax is not valid and not meaningful.  Perhaps, doable if only one of `$2` or `$3` exists (mutually exclusive).  What do you want to happen when there both `$2` and `$3` are not empty?

Comment: I add a input files and output what I want..

Comment: I would like to compare $2 and $3 column from 1st file with $2 form 2nd file and if there is match print to output $4 column from 1st file to second file, if no match, print "-" thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{f2[$2]=f3[$3]=$4;next} 
              {k=$2; suf=((k in f2)?f2[k]:((k in f3)?f3[k]:"-")); 
               $2=k "\t" suf}1' file{1,2} 

chr1 11796321   MTHFR G 0 WILD ADP=1026
chr1 169549811  F5 C 0 WILD ADP=940
chr1 173917078  SERPINC1 C 0 WILD ADP=501
chr2 48962782   FSHR C T HET ADP=1665
chr4 121696962  ANXA5 C T HET ADP=212
chr4 121697011  ANXA5 A 0 WILD ADP=184
chr4 121697037  ANXA5 T 0 WILD ADP=111
chr4 121697037  ANXA5 tccc 0 INDEL AINDEL
chr4 121697056  ANXA5 C 0 WILD ADP=112
chr11 46739505  F2 G 0 WILD ADP=202
chr13 20189511  GJB2 C 0 WILD ADP=326
chr13 20189546  GJB2 AC A INDEL ADP=164
chr13 20189547  GJB2 C 0 WILD ADP=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` (edited to include `$4`) maybe:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$3]=$1 FS $3 FS $4;next} ($2 in A){print A[$2],$3,$4,$5,$6}' file1 file2

chr1 11796321 MTHFR G 0 WILD ADP=1026
chr1 169549811 F5 C 0 WILD ADP=940
chr1 173917078 SERPINC1 C 0 WILD ADP=501
chr2 48962782 FSHR C T HET ADP=1665
chr4 121696962 ANXA5 C T HET ADP=212
chr4 121697011 ANXA5 A 0 WILD ADP=184
chr4 121697037 ANXA5 T 0 WILD ADP=111
chr4 121697037 ANXA5 tccc 0 INDEL AINDEL
chr4 121697056 ANXA5 C 0 WILD ADP=112
chr11 46739505 F2 G 0 WILD ADP=202
chr13 20189511 GJB2 C 0 WILD ADP=326
chr13 20189547 GJB2 C 0 WILD ADP=3
```